# WebKit on th iPhone: is it possible to copy text to the clipboad with JavaScript

Tags: iphone, copy, webkit, web-applications

The iPhone 3.0 software added copy/paste, and native application can programmatically copy content to the clipboard. Is it possible to do the same, i.e. copy text to the clipboard, from JavaScript code running inside Safari on the iPhone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the desktop, copy/paste in websites typically seems to use an embedded Flash gizmo; obviously on the iPhone that's neither possible nor desirable. You might try one of the `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` techniques discussed in Nick Dalton's presentation [here](http://iPhoneIncubator.com/files/NickDalton_360iDev_Sept2009.pdf) to pull information out of your web view, then call an appropriate `UIPasteboard` method.

edit: My apologies—didn't read the post correctly. If it's in the main Safari app as opposed to one whose `UIWebView` you control, I don't think there is a way to force a copy. [Glyphboard](http://mrgan.com/gb/) (site only works from within non-desktop Safari) is an example of a site that would probably be making use of this functionality if it existed.